# django-activity-stream with aggregation

Tags: django, django-activity-stream

I'm using `django-activity-stream` to create a feed of goals. A simplified version of Goal object is as follows:

```py
class Goal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="goals", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_by = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="goals_cheered")
    title = models.CharField(_("title"), max_length=80)
```

There are 2 actions in place: the goal should appear in the feed once it's created and once it has been completed. Then users can like the goal, and here's where I'm stuck: adding the 'likes' count on the feed.

This was the (failed) attempt that made the most sense to me so far:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch

goal_qs = Goal.objects.annotate(likes=Count("liked_by"))
prefetch = [Prefetch("action_object", queryset=goal_qs)]

# in a `group` feed:
qs = group.target_actions.all().prefetch_related("actor__profile").prefetch_related(*prefetch)
```

This gives me a `ValueError`: "Custom queryset can't be used for this lookup."
Maybe it's because django-activity-stream uses GFKs?

How can I get a count of likes? Can I limit the content_type somehow?

**Update**

Managed to get is work by using the `{{ goal.liked_by.all|length }}` on the template. Not really comfortable with that solution, especially in a ListView. It felt super unoptimized.

Comment: More information on what is `group`, `target_actions` and how it's related to `Goal` might help to give a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed sub-optimal. But with generic foreign keys I'm afraid you can't do much better. However, `{{ goal.liked_by.count }}` would still be much more efficient than `{{ goal.liked_by.all|length }}`.